# R1C1 using a variable to set row number (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, variables, excel-formula

Need assistance using a variable in R1C1 formula to set row number.
Goal is to use variable **"lngAccount_ER"** to replace hard code **"120"** in formula end-rows

```
lngAccount_ER = xxx

.Cells(1, 34).FormulaArray = "=INDEX(R12C29:R120C29,MATCH(RC31&R10C&R9C,R12C22:R120C22&R12C28:R120C28&R12C27:R120C27,0))"
```

I attempted the below, but im sure my syntax is off:

```
.Cells(1, 34).FormulaArray = "=INDEX(R12C29:R & lngAccount_ER & C29,MATCH(RC31&R10C&R9C,R12C22:R& lngAccount_ER & C22&R12C28:R& lngAccount_ER & C28&R12C27:R & lngAccount_ER & C27,0))"
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you are mixing a "hard-coded" `String` with a variable, you need to close the string with `"` and add the `&`. The same goes after the variable, add the `&` and also the `"` before the next string.

You were close, modify your line:

```
.Cells(1, 34).FormulaArray = "=INDEX(R12C29:R & lngAccount_ER & C29,MATCH(RC31&R10C&R9C,R12C22:R& lngAccount_ER & C22&R12C28:R& lngAccount_ER & C28&R12C27:R & lngAccount_ER & C27,0))"
```

To:

```
.Cells(1, 34).FormulaArray = "=INDEX(R12C29:R" & lngAccount_ER & "C29,MATCH(RC31&R10C&R9C,R12C22:R" & lngAccount_ER & "C22&R12C28:R" & lngAccount_ER & "C28&R12C27:R" & lngAccount_ER & "C27,0))"
```